# Do Demon Hunter sentries benefit from Big Bad Voodoo?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Do the attack speed and damage buffs from a Witch Doctor's [Big Bad Voodoo](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Big%20Bad%20Voodoo) spell (Slam Dance rune) affect the sentries of a Demon Hunter?

I have never heard a clear answer on whether or not sentries count as pets; if they do, they should be buffed when the caster is standing in BBV's radius. If not, are they buffed when the sentry itself is in the radius?

If it matters, I'm playing D3:ROS on Xbox One, using patch 2.4.1 or newer.

Comment: DH sentries were made into pets in a patch a while ago (2.2 or 2.3 I think). You can easily test if they are pets with the [Tasker and Theo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tasker-and-theo) gloves.

Comment: You can easily test if they are pets by looking up best Marauder builds and checking if Tasker is in those :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sentries are definitely counted as pets. So they will get boosted by Big Bad Voodoo if they are within its range.

However, if you are thinking of the Marauder 4p bonus that fires your attacks, those attacks are not counted as part of your pets. They are counted as YOUR own attacks and will get any bonuses that you do, including that of Big Bad Voodoo. So for that to happen, YOU will need to be within BBV's range for those attacks to be boosted.